# Check VAT numbers on VIES

Tags: html, excel, vba, soap

The code below has stopped working since URL was changed from:
http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService
to:
https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/#/vat-validation

What should I correct in order to fix the code?
I would much appreciate your help.

```
Sub VATCHECK()
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sEnv As String
    Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.xmlhttp
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument    'DOMDocument
    Dim sCountryCode As String
    Dim sVATNo As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next

    Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Clear
    If Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row < 2 Then Exit Sub

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        sURL = "https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/#/vat-validation"
        sCountryCode = Range("B" & i).Value
        sVATNo = Range("C" & i).Value
    
        sEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:urn=""urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types"">"
        sEnv = sEnv & "<soapenv:Header/>"
        sEnv = sEnv & "<soapenv:Body>"
        sEnv = sEnv & "<urn:checkVat>"
        sEnv = sEnv & "<urn:countryCode>" & sCountryCode & "</urn:countryCode>"
        sEnv = sEnv & "<urn:vatNumber>" & sVATNo & "</urn:vatNumber>"
        sEnv = sEnv & "</urn:checkVat>"
        sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Body>"
        sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Envelope>"

        With xmlhttp
            .Open "POST", sURL, False
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml;"
            .send sEnv
        
            Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
            xmlDoc.LoadXML .responseText
            
            If Range("A" & i).Value = 0 Then
                Range("D" & i).Value = ""
                Else
                If LCase(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("valid").Item(0).Text) = "true" Then
                    Range("D" & i).Value = "Valid VAT number"
                Else
                    Range("D" & i).Value = "Invalid VAT number"
                End If
            End If
                
        End With

    Next i
  
End Sub
```

Changed URL but the code still does not work.

Comment: Can you give valid examples of `sCountryCode` and `sVATNo` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams, sCountryCode: DK sVATNo: 28505116

Comment: `http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService` works for me

Comment: It always gives me "Valid VAT number" output even if the VAT number is incorrect.

Comment: I was only looking at the xml response - the error comes later in your code - see below

Answer (score 0):

That `On Error Resume Next` is hiding the error from:

```
 If LCase(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("valid").Item(0).Text) = "true" Then
```

needs to be

```
 If LCase(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ns:valid").Item(0).Text) = "true" Then
```

This works for me:

```vb
Sub VATCHECK()
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sEnv As String
    Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.xmlhttp
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument    'DOMDocument
    Dim sCountryCode As String
    Dim sVATNo As String
    Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet, els As Object
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VAT") '<<< use a specific sheet
    
'    On Error Resume Next 'don't use this, except for specific expected errors!!!!
'
    ws.Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Clear
    If ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row < 2 Then Exit Sub

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        sURL = "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService"
        sCountryCode = ws.Range("B" & i).Value
        sVATNo = ws.Range("C" & i).Value
    
        sEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""" & _
               " xmlns:urn=""urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types"">"
        sEnv = sEnv & "<soapenv:Header/>"
        sEnv = sEnv & "<soapenv:Body>"
        sEnv = sEnv & "<urn:checkVat>"
        sEnv = sEnv & "<urn:countryCode>" & sCountryCode & "</urn:countryCode>"
        sEnv = sEnv & "<urn:vatNumber>" & sVATNo & "</urn:vatNumber>"
        sEnv = sEnv & "</urn:checkVat>"
        sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Body>"
        sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Envelope>"

        If ws.Range("A" & i).Value = 0 Then
            ws.Range("D" & i).Value = ""
        Else
            With xmlhttp
                .Open "POST", sURL, False
                .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml;"
                .Send sEnv
                Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
                xmlDoc.LoadXML .responseText
            End With
            
            Set els = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ns2:valid")
            If els.Length > 0 Then 'element is present?
                ws.Range("D" & i).Value = IIf(els(0).Text = "true", _
                                              "Valid VAT number", _
                                              "Invalid VAT number")
            Else
                ws.Range("D" & i).Value = "response error!"
                Debug.Print xmlDoc.xml '<<< check this to see what happened
            End If
        End If
                
    Next i
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, your code is much better. Usually get I proper output but I also got "response error!" for a valid VAT number. I entered DK28505116 seven times. Five times I got "Valid VAT number". Two times I got "Response error!".

Comment: I just queried that same thing 8 times and each time got "Valid VAT number".  If you get "Response error" then you need to look at the returned XML to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I state that I'm working on valid Italian VATs.

Thanks to your help (just changing the reference to MSXML2.XMLHTTP60) I managed to get the script working.
But it no longer extracts the address and the name of the company.
How can I do?
tks

```
Sub VATCHECK()
Dim sURL As String
Dim sEnv As String
Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 'Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.xmlhttp for Microsoft XML, v 6.0
Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60 'DOMDocument
Dim sCountryCode As String
Dim sVATNo As String
Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet, els As Object

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VAT") '<<< use a specific sheet


ws.Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Clear
If ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row < 2 Then Exit Sub

For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    sURL = "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService"
    sCountryCode = ws.Range("B" & i).Value
    sVATNo = ws.Range("C" & i).Value

    sEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""" & _
           " xmlns:urn=""urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types"">"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<soapenv:Header/>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<soapenv:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<urn:checkVat>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<urn:countryCode>" & sCountryCode & "</urn:countryCode>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<urn:vatNumber>" & sVATNo & "</urn:vatNumber>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "</urn:checkVat>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Envelope>"

    If ws.Range("A" & i).Value = 0 Then
        ws.Range("D" & i).Value = ""
    Else
        With xmlhttp
            .Open "POST", sURL, False
            .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml;"
            .Send sEnv
            Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60  'DOMDocument
            xmlDoc.LoadXML .responseText
        End With

        
        
        Set els = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ns2:valid")
       If els.Length > 0 Then 'element is present?
            ws.Range("D" & i).Value = IIf(els(0).Text = "true", _
                                          "Valid VAT number", _
                                          "Invalid VAT number")
        Else
            ws.Range("D" & i).Value = "response error!"
            Debug.Print xmlDoc.XML '<<< check this to see what happened
        End If
    End If
            
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33294657)